# Single quotes changed to double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem that when using single quotes in my javascript those single quotes will be changed to double quotes from the browser

```
var divs = $(".new_spezial > .contentContainer");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='spezial_row'></div>");
}
```

even escaping the single quotes does not help.

```
var divs = $(".new_spezial > .contentContainer");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class=\'spezial_row\'></div>");
}
```

It will always be changed to this in the browser:

```
var divs = $(".new_spezial > .contentContainer");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class="spezial_row"></div>");
}
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: is there any specific reason why you want single quotes?

Comment: If i use double quotes I run intro following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

Also when using single quotes and inserting the Code through the console it works just as inteded.

Comment: Changed _where_? _“How would I fix this?”_ - you would start by explaining what the actual _problem_ is ... please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question about why you would pref single quotes over double in the html. but if you want to use it only in your jquery use `.wrapAll("<div class=\"spezial_row\"></div>")`

Comment: I also want to say for inspection purposes the browser might change singles to doubles, but the browser at runtime should be evaluating quotation as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem it was that in my CMS (Typo3) I had

```
xhtml_cleaning = all
```

activated. Therefore the single quotes were replaced...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this 2 options?

```
var divs = $(".new_spezial > .contentContainer");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="spezial_row"></div>');
}

var divs = $(".new_spezial > .contentContainer");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class=\"spezial_row\"></div>");
}
```